# Mesh Generation help

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh, heat-equation

I am having trouble generating a mesh of a rectangle inside another rectangle. I have been following the steps on this article: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/HeatTransfer/ModelCollection/ShrinkFitting.html

However, I have been getting an error that I cannot combine the inner rectangle to the outer rectangle with a hole in it. It says "Coordinate Skeleton[2] should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form." in the debugger. Here is my code, it is more or less what the tutorial does.

````
bathx = 30;
bathy = 30;
plastic = Rectangle[{10, 10}, {20, 20}];
waterbath = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {bathx, bathy}], plastic]; 
\[CapitalOmega] = RegionUnion[plastic, waterbath]; 
bounds = 1.1*{{0, bathx}, {0, bathy}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], bounds];

Show[mesh["Wireframe"]]

Subscript[bm, w] = ToBoundaryMesh[waterbath]; 
Subscript[bm, p] = ToBoundaryMesh[plastic];
ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
bmesh = FEMUtils`BoundaryElementMeshJoin[Subscript[bm, w], 
  Subscript[bm, p]]

waterbathCoordinate = {1, 1};
plasticCoordinate = {15, 15};
markerColors = {Blue, Orange};
markerCoordinates = {{waterbathCoordinate}, {plasticCoordinate}};

Show[{bmesh["Wireframe"], 
  Graphics[MapThread[{PointSize[0.02], #1, 
      Point /@ #2} &, {markerColors, markerCoordinates}]]}]  

markerSpecification = {{plasticCoordinate, 1}, {waterbathCoordinate, 
    2}};

mesh2 = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> markerSpecification, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> 5*10^-6];
GraphicsRow[{mesh2[
   "Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> 
     Map[Directive[FaceForm[#], EdgeForm[]] &, markerColors]]], 
  mesh2["Wireframe"[
    Sequence[PlotRange -> {bounds}, 
     "MeshElementStyle" -> Map[FaceForm[#] &, markerColors]]]]}]

Show[{mesh2["Wireframe"]}]
```
````

Comment: Your MaxCellMeasure on mesh2 is tiny and it crashed my kernel.  Try something more like `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1`.

Answer (score 7):

The linked example was for a much smaller domain and hence too small of a mesh size specification.  The following code should accomplish what you need.

```
(* Uncomment if not installed *)
(*ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][]*)
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
bathx = 30;
bathy = 30;
bounds = 1.1*{{0, bathx}, {0, bathy}};
plastic = Rectangle[{10, 10}, {20, 20}];
waterbath = Rectangle[{0, 0}, {bathx, bathy}];

bmw = ToBoundaryMesh[waterbath];
bmp = ToBoundaryMesh[plastic];
bmesh = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bmw, bmp];

waterbathCoordinate = {1, 1};
plasticCoordinate = {15, 15};
markerColors = {Blue, Orange};
markerCoordinates = {{waterbathCoordinate}, {plasticCoordinate}};

Show[{bmesh["Wireframe"], 
  Graphics[MapThread[{PointSize[0.02], #1, 
      Point /@ #2} &, {markerColors, markerCoordinates}]]}]

markerSpecification = {{plasticCoordinate, 1}, {waterbathCoordinate, 
    2}};

mesh2 = ToElementMesh[bmesh, "RegionMarker" -> markerSpecification, 
   "MaxCellMeasure" -> {"Length" -> 1}];
GraphicsRow[{mesh2[
   "Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> 
     Map[Directive[FaceForm[#], EdgeForm[]] &, markerColors]]], 
  mesh2["Wireframe"[
    Sequence[PlotRange -> {bounds}, 
     "MeshElementStyle" -> Map[FaceForm[#] &, markerColors]]]]}]
mesh2["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6):

Tim's answer is spot on. Here is a slightly different approach that uses a trick. The idea is to use the `waterbath` as the region and tell `ToElementMesh` to also mesh the interior region (the plastic). If this approach is applicable in your case then you can reduce the amount of code  somewhat.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
bathx = 30;
bathy = 30;
plastic = Rectangle[{10, 10}, {20, 20}];
waterbath = 
  RegionDifference[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {bathx, bathy}], plastic];
waterbathCoordinate = {1, 1};
plasticCoordinate = {15, 15};
markerColors = {Blue, Orange};
markerSpecification = {{plasticCoordinate, 1, 
    0.25}, {waterbathCoordinate, 2, 1.}};
mesh = ToElementMesh[waterbath, "RegionHoles" -> None, 
  "RegionMarker" -> markerSpecification]
GraphicsRow[{mesh[
   "Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> 
     Map[Directive[FaceForm[#], EdgeForm[]] &, markerColors]]], 
  mesh["Wireframe"[
    "MeshElementStyle" -> Map[FaceForm[#] &, markerColors]]]}]
```

[image]

Also, note that I used a different granularity in the subsections of the mesh.